# gdb alias for quick saving/loading of breakpoints

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

So I'm pretty new to gdb, and have just learned that you can save breakpoints with:

```
save breakpoints filename
```

and load them with

```
source filename
```

which is great, but because it's something I more or less plan on doing every time I enter/exit gdb, I'd like to get it down to a quick alias.

So, in my ~/.gdbinit I have the lines

```
alias savebps = save breakpoints .gdb_bps
alias loadbps = source .gdb_bps
loadbps
```

Unfortunately, every time I open gdb I get the error:

```
Invalid command to alias to: save breakpoints .gdb_bps
```

I know(/ strongly think) I have the syntax correct, as I've tested

```
alias savebps = help
```

and that alias works. So I think it's an issue with having a non-gdb command word (the filename) as part of an alias.

So, my questions are this:

- Am I being totally stupid and there's already a great way to auto-save and maintain my list of breakpoints?
- Can GDB have filenames in aliases? Or am I looking for something other than an 'alias'?
- If they CAN have filenames in them, what am I doing wrong?

Oh and as a note the '.gdb_bps' is an arbitrary file name I just kinda came up with as it'd be a nice unobtrusive thing to easily .gitignore and stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can GDB have filenames in aliases?

Looks like no. It looks like aliases can't have any arguments to commands, not only filenames. This alias fails also:

```
(gdb) alias spe = set print elements 0
Invalid command to alias to: set print elements 0
```

> Or am I looking for something other than an 'alias'?

Yes, you can use [user-defined command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html) instead:

```
(gdb) define savebps
Type commands for definition of "savebps".
End with a line saying just "end".
>save breakpoints .gdb_bps
>end
(gdb) 
(gdb) define loadbps
Type commands for definition of "loadbps".
End with a line saying just "end".
>source .gdb_bps
>end
(gdb)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!

And for those wondering, you can put defines in .gdbinit line separated without the prompts as you'd expect.